# Angular language service detect HTML as Typescript

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular8

Currently i'm working on a project, and had to update NodeJs to 12.7.0 and to Angular 8. After these updates IntelliJ Idea detect HTML as Typescript, and i got a lot of warning because of missing HTML tags.

I got this error: `ts2304: cannot find name 'div'`

Comment: Show the code you have the error

Comment: sorry @TonyNgo, but i can't share my companies project

Comment: What IDEA version do you work with? Similar issue ([WEB-36373](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36373)) is fixed in 2018.3.3; as a workaround, please try disabling Angular service in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**

Comment: @lena disabling the Angular service solved the problem, my idea version is 2018.3.2 so that's the problem, thanks